# Arduino serial communication issue

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to write a simple program to read serial data from Arduino. In the Arduino serial monitor window, everything works fine. In the Python console, each number is on a separate line. In Pycharm, it just shows `b' '`. I don't know where the problem is.

**Arduino Serial Monitor**:

```
1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890

1234567890
```

**Python 3 console**:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

0
```

**Pycharm IDE**:

```
b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '

b' '
```

Here is the Python 3 code I am using:

```py
import serial
from time import sleep

Ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=0)
Counter = 1

while Counter <= 10:
    data = Ser.readline()
    print(data)
    sleep(1)
    Counter += 1
Ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    Serial.println(1234567890);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a side effect of `timeout=0`. I would try this:

```
import serial

Ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600, timeout=1)
data = Ser.readline()
print(data)
Ser.close()
```

Comment: b'1234567890\r\n', How can i convert it to: 1234567890?

Comment: Provided that `data = b'1234567890\r\n'` then `int(data)` gives you `1234567890`.

Comment: If your data is not numbers (perhaps letters or something else) then use: `data = b'1meh7890\r\n'` `print(data.decode())`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **AMD** module !!

Link to the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/AMD/

**AMD** is a **powerful Data-Science module built especially for data extraction and communication with Arduino**.
This module **automatically filters all escape sequence characters** and returns you a piece of data or a **list of data** from the Arduino!

Install via pip:  **`pip install AMD`**

Documentation for ardata function in the link: https://github.com/SayadPervez/AMD-SEPERATE-DOCUMENTATION/blob/master/ardata().md

**Your entire python code can be replaced with the below two lines!!**

```py
from AMD import *
data = ardata(3,lines=10)
```

**Alternatively, you can also use the below modified line to get more functionality**

```
data = ardata('COM3',lines=10,squeeze=False,numeric=True)
```

> > > The **first parameter** is the **COM port**. It can either be a string or an Integer.
> > >       **`lines`** represent the **number of lines of data to be read** from the serial monitor.
> > >       **`squeeze`** parameter specifies if data has to be compressed.**`numeric`** specifies if the expected data is of numeric type(integers or floats).**However for your requirement the first two lines of code are enough since the rest are set by default!**